# "Непосильное прочим прошлое" - необходим ли предлог? читается ли предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, стилистика

> Белград переполнен мрачным достоинством, словно тяжкая чаша. И сны
>   этого непосильного прочим прошлого можно рассмотреть только сквозь его
>   полузакрытые веки.

[Управление в русском языке](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

> **НЕПОСИЛЬНЫЙ (непосилен)** для кого. *Непосильная для ребёнка тяжесть; Работа для них непосильна.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, не читается, я даже сразу не поняла, зачем здесь "прочим". **Непосильного для прочих** будет лучше смотреться.

Видимо, произошла некорректная подмена: **Непосильный для кого / не под силу кому.**